# Can't create file ftp Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp

I've configured my vsftpd, I wanted to jail user to their directory, but I was getting this

```
vsftpd: refusing to run with writable root inside chroot()
```

so I put this command, but I was getting, and it worked

sudo chmod a-w /home/to/my/dir

but now I'm getting

```
COMMAND:>   [11/21/2012 12:01:13 AM] STOR SQLyogTunnel.php
        [11/21/2012 12:01:14 AM] 553 Could not create file.
ERROR:>     [11/21/2012 12:01:14 AM] Access denied.
```

on uploading file, kindly help me to resolve this.

Thank u

Comment: I also tried [allow_writeable_chroot=YES] in vsftpd.conf to jail user but it wasn't working so I've to put that chown a-w command

Answer (score 0):

You have a few possibilities:

1. Remove write permission on home directory for the user and make subdirectory that is writeable
2. Set `local_root=/home` in the configuration, that would chroot to /home
3. Choose a different ftp daemon such as pure-ftpd.

In a later version vsftpd includes a `allow_writeable_chroot` directive, however the version shipped with ubuntu does not include that.

You could backport the vsftpd from debian unstable though (assuming you're on ubuntu 12.04 or 12.10):

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential devscripts
sudo apt-get build-dep vsftpd

mkdir ~/build
cd ~/build

wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/v/vsftpd/vsftpd_3.0.2-1.dsc \
     http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/v/vsftpd/vsftpd_3.0.2.orig.tar.xz \
     http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/v/vsftpd/vsftpd_3.0.2-1.debian.tar.xz

dpkg-source -x vsftpd_3.0.2-1.dsc
cd vsftpd-3.0.2

# After the following an editor will popup where you can add a
# short changelog entry such as "ported from debian unstable" 
# and than save and exit

# For Ubuntu 12.04
dch -R -D precise

# For Ubuntu 12.10
dch -R -D quantal

dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -rfakeroot
```

After that you'll end up with a `vsftpd_3.0.2-1build1_*.deb` in `~/build` just install it using the following command:

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/build/vsftpd_3.0.2-1build1_*.deb
```

After that the `allow_writeable_chroot` directive should work.

Comment: thanks, I've tried it but this command get error  sudo dpkg -i vsftpd_3.0.2-1build1_*.deb

Comment: cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /home/ubuntu/build/vsftpd_3.0.2-1build1_*.deb
ubuntu@ip-10-38-106-212:~/build/vsftpd-3.0.2$ sudo dpkg -i vsftpd_3.0.2-1build1_*.deb
dpkg: error processing vsftpd_3.0.2-1build1_*.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 vsftpd_3.0.2-1build1_*.deb

Comment: I've connected to ftp but can't upload file

Comment: well didn't you get any error while dpkg-buildpackage? do `ls ~/build` to see what files resulted from the build...